# Не работает событие нажатие клавиши C#

Tags: c#, winforms, keydown

Возникла проблема, не работает событие нажатие клавиши в форме.

```
private void Form1_KeyDown_1(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Up && sn.course != Snake.Course.DOWN)
    {
        sn.course = Snake.Course.UP;
    }
    if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Down && sn.course != Snake.Course.UP)
    {
        sn.course = Snake.Course.DOWN;
    }
    if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Left && sn.course != Snake.Course.RIGHT)
    {
        sn.course = Snake.Course.LEFT;
    }
    if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Right && sn.course != Snake.Course.LEFT)
    {
        sn.course = Snake.Course.RIGHT;
    }
}
```

Класс `Snake` написан в другом файле. В классе `Form1` создано поле `public Snake sn;`
Вот поля класса `Snake`

```
public class Snake
{
    public List<Rectangle> lSnake = new List<Rectangle>();
    private int sLong = 3;
    public int addX, addY;
    public enum Course
    {
        UP,
        DOWN,
        LEFT,
        RIGHT
    };
    public Course course;
}
```

Comment: Да, я уже известил Microsoft. Они исправят C# к следующему выпуску. Раньше никто почему-то не замечал, что нажатие на клавиши в форме не работает.

Comment: Просто прикол в том, что если запущу другой код, где все в 1 файле, все прекрасно работает.

Comment: Да? Ну слава богу, тогда всё отменяется.

Comment: Тогда в чем же может быть проблема?

Comment: А вам не приходил в голову вариант, что с событием нажатия кнопки проблем нет, а они в вашем коде? Ну, чисто теоретически, я ничего не имею в виду?

Comment: Рискну предположить что разные части программы у вас находятся в несвязанных пространствах имен.

Comment: Пространство имен одно и то же, а по поводу события была идея, но я не знаю как ее проверить, тк при дебагинке не знаю как вызвать событие нажатия кнопки, а если остановку программы ставлю внутри этого метода, то туда просто не заходит.

Comment: А скиньте куда-нибудь проект целиком в архиве, если, конечно, он не представляет коммерческую тайну

Comment: Вот ссылка на проект https://yadi.sk/d/PhCjfhsrk2vVH

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Установите в окне Properties формы Form1 значение свойства `KeyPreview = true`,
или

```
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    this.KeyPreview = true;
}
```

Comment: Огромное спасибо! Все теперь работает!

Comment: Если не трудно отметь ответ как правильный.